# Symmetric matrix $S$ with collapsed eignevalues $\lambda_i=\alpha$ implies $S=\alpha I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $S$ whose eigenvalues all collapse to a single eigenvalue $\alpha$. Show that $S = \alpha I$.

From this it is clear that the characteristic equation must be $(\lambda - \alpha)^n$ and it's easy to see that $S = \alpha I$ fits the bill here but I can't seem to show why it does so necessarily?

Answer (score 2):

Every real-symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. Since our matrix $S$ has only one eigenvalue $\alpha$, this implies that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$
S=P(\alpha I)P^{-1}=\alpha\cdot P\cdot I\cdot P^{-1}=\alpha\cdot P\cdot P^{-1}=\alpha\cdot I
$$